# What is the simplest python equivalent to R `:` operator to create a sequence of numbers outside indexing

Tags: python

Is there a simple Python equivalent to R's `:` operator to create a vector of numbers? I only found `range()`.

Example:

```r
vector_example <- 1:4
vector_example
```

Output:

```r
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Why exactly does `range()` not meet your requirement...?

Comment: may you want it to be a list. `list(range(1,4))`

Comment: Hey @Sinval, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

I remember being frustrated by the lack of `:` to create sequences of consecutive numbers when I first switched from R to Python. In general, there is no direct equivalent to the `:` operator. Python sequences are more like  R's `seq()` function.

While the base function `range` is alright, I personally prefer `numpy.arange`, as it is more flexible.

```py
import numpy as np
# Create a simple array from 1 through 4
np.arange(1, 5)
# This is what I mean by "more flexible"
np.arange(1, 5).tolist()
```

Remember that Python lists and arrays are 0-indexed. As far as I'm concerned, all intervals are right-open too. So `np.arange(a, b)` will exclude `b`.

PS: There are other functions, such as `numpy.linspace` which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `range()`.  That's the standard answer for Python's equivalent.  It returns a sequence.  If you want the equivalent in a Python list, just create a list from the sequence returned by `range()`:

```
range_list = list(range(1,5))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I don't know 'go', but from your example, it appears that its `:` operator's second argument is inclusive...that is, that number is included in the resulting sequence.  This is not true of Python's `range()` function.  The second parameter passed to it is not included in the resulting sequence.  So where you use `4` in your example, you want to use `5` with Python to get the same result.